# Type 'IProductsAvailable' is missing the following properties from type 'IProductsAvailable[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more

Tags: angular

Can anyone help me with the following error when trying to use an interface in my application

```
Type 'IProductsAvailable' is missing the following properties from type 'IProductsAvailable[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more
```

*Service*

```
getProducts() {
  return this.http.get<IProductsAvailable>("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
}
```

*Interface*

```
export interface IProductsAvailable {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    category: string;
    description: number;
    image: string;
    price: number;
    rating: []
}
```

Component

```
 productsAvailable:IProductsAvailable[];

 this._productsService.getProducts().subscribe((res)=> {
   console.log(res);
   this.productsAvailable = res;
 });
```

When I try to assign the response from the service to the `productsAvailable` variable I get the error.

Comment: Probably should call the http service expecting an array instead of a single entry `...get<IProductsAvailable[]>`

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, please make it as the answer then I'll mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

In your service, you should specify that the generic type should be an array.

```
getProducts() {
  return this.http.get<IProductsAvailable[]>("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
}
```

Comment: I would probably write `IProductsAvailable[]` as `Array<IProductsAvailable>`

Comment: @Kshitij why???

Comment: Because this is the new way to define arrays in typescript

Answer (score 0):

Change service to this :

```
getProducts(): Observable<Array<IProductsAvailable>> {

  return this.http.get<Array<IProductsAvailable>>
      ("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");

}
```